# DataGridView Copy a selected row issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview and i want to copy the exact row that gets selected by the user to the same position (above).  I have it right now so it inserts the line above the current line that is selected but it is not copying all the values.
I'm just using a basic grid, no dataset or datatables. heres my code.

```
       If dgvPcPrevMonth.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        dgvPcPrevMonth.Rows.Insert(dgvPcPrevMonth.CurrentCell.RowIndex,  dgvPcPrevMonth.SelectedRows(0).Clone)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Select a row before you copy")
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clone method only clones the row, not the data in it. You'll have to loop through the columns and add the values yourself after inserting it

```
Public Function CloneWithValues(ByVal row As DataGridViewRow) _
    As DataGridViewRow

    CloneWithValues = CType(row.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
    For index As Int32 = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
        CloneWithValues.Cells(index).Value = row.Cells(index).Value
    Next 

End Function
```

The code is taken directly from the msdn link provided below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Surprising ! I didn't ever imagine that the Clone method didn't copy the cell content :(

Comment: The word clone does kind of imply an exact copy. But if you think about it, If you clone a person then only the body would be an exact copy. The data contained inside that person would have to be developed.    Microsoft is deep. :)

Comment: wow.. thats dumb...and ya it worked.. just you would think clone with clone the whole thing...

Comment: Yeah it confused me a bit too when I first encountered it, glad to hear its now working for you. Don't forget to accept it as the answer for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code to test if current row was not the first and to clone the cuurent row (not the first one).

```
 If ddgvPcPrevMonth.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0 Then
    dgvPcPrevMonth.Rows.Insert(dgvPcPrevMonth.CurrentCell.RowIndex,  dgvPcPrevMonth.Rows(dgvPcPrevMonth.CurrentCell.RowIndex-1).Clone)
 Else
    MessageBox.Show("Select a row (but not the first one) before you copy")
End If
```

Comment: Right : I missed the "SelectedRows". I update my code replacing it by "Rows".

Comment: what happens is.. i had this before.. is the row that gets copied.. in the first column i have this DataGridViewRow { Index=-1 }  . and all the other columns are blank.. still not working.

Comment: Is your first column autoincrement ?